# Feature engineering, handling missing data

Tags: machine-learning, classification, missing-data

Consider this data table

```
NumberOfAccidents   MeanDistance
1                   5
3                   0
0                   NA
0                   NA
6                   1.2
2                   0
```

the first feature is the number of accidents and the second is the average distance of these accidents to a certain point. It is obvious for a record with zero accident, there won't be a value for `MeanDistance`. However, imputing these missing values are not logical!

**MY SOLUTION:** I have decided to discretize the `MeanDistance` with `NAs` being a level (bin) and the rest of the data being in bins like: `[0,1), [1,2.5), [2.5, Inf)`. the final table will look like this:

```
NumberOfAccidents   NAs   first_bin   sec_bin     third_bin
1                   0     0           0           1
3                   0     1           0           0
0                   1     0           0           0
0                   1     0           0           0
6                   0     0           1           0
2                   0     1           0           0
```

What is your idea with these types of missing values that cannot be imputed?
what is your solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the domain and what you are trying to predict. Even though your solution is fine, I wouldn't bin the rest of the data as you did. Giving that the `NumberOfAccidents` feature already tells what `MeanDistance` have `NA` values, I would probably just impute `0` into the `NA` values (for computations) and leave the rest of the data as it is.

Nevertheless, there is no need to limit yourself, just try different approaches and keep the one that boost your `KPI` (Key Performance Indicator).

Comment: It is a part of a binary classification problem. you meant to have pairs as (0,0) will work instead of (0, NA)?  I have many features like this in my data set and I have to come up with a robust solution.

Comment: Yes, based on the case you've described, I believe this would work. However, gut feeling is not something you should trust, just try it out and see if it boost your model, if it doesn't just discard the idea.

Regarding to the other features with `NA` values, are they also dependent on the `NumberOfAccidents` ?

Comment: my first solution was the same as your idea, and I am thinking of discretizing the values. I have groups of features: `NumberOfAccident_60` which counts the accidents in last 60 minutes and some features relying on the last 60 minutes accidents, such as counts of types of accidents, `MeanDist_60`, `MinDist_60` and etc. there other groups of features counting the last 90 minutes accidents and so on... but `NA's` of each group depend on the zero values of the first feature of each group (`NumberOfAccident_60` and `NumberOfAccident_90`)

Comment: Got it. As long as these intervals `[0,1), [1,2.5), [2.5, Inf)` are well chosen, your solution seems fine for this particular problem. But as I previously said, there is no harm in trying both approaches and see which gives you a better result.